# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/parseException although jar is already there

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar, dependencies

This image:

[image: This image]

shows that the jar file is in the output directory but i get this error

> ~ java -jar .\TelePriceBotGUI.jar
>
> Error: Unable to initialize main class org.ariyan.App Caused by:
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/ParseException`

In Project Structure > Artifacts > Output Layout: i tried moving json-simple from available elements to  but no luck

Comment: *java -jar .\TelePriceBotGUI.jar* That would have to be a 'fat jar' made with Maven Shade for that to work